# Multiple Servers, Multiple Drive Failure within 12 hours?

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

In the IT world I just won the Lottery Twice....

Today we had a hard drive fail in a raid array. A few hours later we had another drive fail on a different server.... We started checking all the environmental logs and systems immediately. Humidity is 40%, temp is at 75*, no dust or other particulates flying around. We checked the UPS logs, no spikes reported. About 3 hours later another hard drive failed on a 3rd system....

To recap 3 HP DL380 G7's, these servers are all sequential serial numbers. The drives are not from the same lot though I bet the array controllers and boards are. HP will be out in the morning.... In the meantime we are hoping this does not become a habit... We have had 1 drive fail in this entire server rack in 2.5 years. Today 3 within 12 hours!

What else should we be looking for? Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated. This incident has consumed our spares.... If we have another fail we will be looking for HP to swap them.

Update: These are 146 GB 10k rpm SAS Drives and one 300 GB 10k rpm SAS Drive. HP original equipment.

Comment: Did someone [yell at the server rack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDacjrSCeq4)?

Comment: I had the same problem 5 years ago: http://serverfault.com/q/22448/7709 - oh shit... that was 5 years ago. Damn I'm feeling old...

Comment: You could also have had a heat or other environmental problem in the past, that impacted these drives, and they just failed now.

Answer (score 3):

These things happen... You'd be surprised what I've seen withe the same equipment at scale.

You did right by checking your environment for [ESD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge), temperature and power issues.

Being ProLiant DL380 G7 units, the array controllers are embedded on the system board. Lot numbers aren't controlled too tightly there. I don't think this is anything beyond coincidence. However, this may be a good time for some firmware updates, as false drive failures are sometimes symptomatic of bad revisions.

Since you have support, let HP deal with the parts/replacement and move on :)

BTW - It would be helpful to detail the drive capacities and type involved (SAS, SATA, Nearline SAS)

Comment: I added the drive type. These are 146 gb SAS drives and one 300GB SAS drive

Comment: @DaffyDuc They fail. I have a pile of 18 146GB 10k SAS disks that need to be sent back for warranty repair.

Comment: I know these are mechanical, they are going to fail however the probability of having no failures over the course of 3 years and then 3 in one day is pretty incredible. I can believe its just dumb luck however I want to ensure we have covered all of our bases before handing in an incident report that indicates a black swan visited and brought his purple brother... :) Thank you for posting though... I hope by the end of the week I don't have the same stack... lol

Comment: I think [@dennis-kaarsemaker](http://serverfault.com/users/144990/dennis-kaarsemaker) has [a really helpful image](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8815130#8815130) of drive failure rates for large installs.

Comment: Short of firmware on the controllers (some revisions reported false failures), this is what it is. You may want to take this time to update system firmware anyway.